# Discovering IP restrictions in Visual SVN Server - Access denied from new IP

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, visualsvn-server, tortoisesvn

I have an installation of Visual SVN (Server Standard Edition, C 2007-2016) that I have inherited, and I am trying to give a new programmer remote access and having some difficulty. It is installed on a server running Windows Server 2012 R2, being accessed using Tortoise SVN. The server is behind a firewall (Cisco ASA).

Windows firewall rule:

Allow, no over ride, local and remote address are any, TCP protocol, all other settings are all/yes/allow or any.

Firewall:

Inbound rule (Jumpbox that works, with static IP)

Permit [xxx.xx.xx.0]/24 -> [server ip]/32 [port] TCP

Inbound rule (Server that currently times out and doesn't resolve)

Permit [xxx.xx.xx.0]/32 -> [server ip]/32 [port] TCP

The httpd-custom.conf file in the Visual SVN directory is empty.

I'm using the same user account on both (Currently mine, until I figure out how to give his account access). When I put in the URL in Tortoise on the first IP (my jumpbox), it resolves immediately and asks for SVN credentials. On the second IP (desktop), I get a "Please wait while the repository browser is initializing" that never resolves.

For clarification, the first is a jumpbox that has a permanently static IP. The second has a mutable IP, however I did a whoami, added the firewall rule for that IP and it will not allow access. I confirmed the IP did not change in between adding the rule and attempting access. I also changed the IP address in the original working firewall rule which broke access from the jumpbox. Access was restored after changing it back.

Is there a conf file or other place that would restrict access that I am missing?

Comment: I erased my answer, just re-read, that the second rule with the /32 rule match your IP. I would maybe do a simple wireshark on the SVN server, to see if the server can see the packet or not. As it can be a turtoisesvn bug too, see that q/a for example; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345876/tortoisesvn-is-running-very-slow

Comment: @yagmoth555 - I've now tried with from my work laptop, home laptop (Without virus protection), using both tortoise and smart svn. They all time out/won't connect.